# C# math.pow cube root calculation

Tags: c#, cube

How can I calculate a cube root of `(0.015*(0.05*0.05))`?

I tried the following solutions:

```
double result = Math.Pow(0.015 * (0.05 * 0.05), 1.0/3.0);
```

and I am getting `0.03347`.
The same calculation from Volframalpha: `0.015*(0.05*0.05)^0.33` gives `0.00207`.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: They are two different calculations.

Comment: you're missing parentheses in second example `(0.015*(0.05*0.05))^0.33`

Comment: Try this on WA - `(0.015*(0.05*0.05))^(1/3)` - and it'll give you the same result as in your C# code.

Comment: Hi Aleksey, Enigmativity, but I`m having trouble to get this in C#. no matter where the brackets are i`m still getting 0.03347 and should be 0.00207. double result = Math.Pow((0.015 * (0.05 * 0.05)), 1.0 / 3.0); = 0.03347 and double result = Math.Pow(0.015 * (0.05 * 0.05), 1.0 / 3.0); = also 0.3347. How to get 0.00207 ?

Comment: @Thomas You don't. The formula you typed into WolframAlpha (`etc^0.33`) is not precise. `1/3 = 0.33333333333333333...` (repeating forever). No decimal expansion can represent it accurately. But if you [input the formula using `1/3` instead](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(0.015*(0.05*0.05))%5E(1%2F3)), you get the same results as C#.

Comment: @Thomas: You calculate (0.05 * 0.05)^0.3 * 0.015 in wolfram. If you want to do this in c# you need to type `0.015 * Math.Pow(0.05 * 0.05, 1/3.0)`

Comment: Hi Kroltan thank`s a lot for that. I`m trying to achieve the result of calculation: 0.3* ((0.0015*0.793700526) + (0.0015*square root (0.7071068)) + (0.015* (((0.05*0.05) ^ (0.33))))) by coding in C#. If you paste this in to WA this will give 0.0013 which is correct, but I can`t get this to work in C#. The part I was asking for above was taken from this equation, I`m trying to brake it apart.

Comment: @Thomas: so this is correct. You're not looking for a cube root of `(0.015*(0.05*0.05))` but for a cube root of `(0.05*0.05)` times `0.015` - you mismatched the parentheses

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for help, that works :-). I will try to convert this long equation now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are three concerns that I have.

1. You are utilizing Math.Pow() in one part of your expression, however, you will want to use Math.Sqrt() in the first part of the expression which was later given during the conversation.
2. Secondly, there is an issue with the parenthetical groupings within the expression causing a invalid evaluation of the expression
3. Thirdly, you will need to use the 'd' character suffix after your numerical values that do not have a decimal value to evaluate the expected result.

The equation:
(0.3d * ((0.0015d * (0.793700526d + Math.Sqrt(0.7071068))) + (0.015d * Math.Pow((0.05d * 0.05d), (1d/3d)))))

The code:

```
using System;

namespace POW
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Corrected calculation derived from comment conversation given by author
            double myCalculation1 = (0.3 * ((0.0015 * (0.793700526 + Math.Sqrt(0.7071068))) + (0.015 * Math.Pow((0.05 * 0.05), (1 / 3)))));

            // d suffix used to ensure the non decimal value is treated as a decimal
            double myCalculation2 = (0.3 * ((0.0015 * (0.793700526 + Math.Sqrt(0.7071068))) + (0.015 * Math.Pow((0.05 * 0.05), (1d/3d)))));

            // Output the value of myPow
            Console.WriteLine("The value of myCalculation is: {0}", myCalculation1);
            Console.WriteLine("The value of myCalculation is: {0}", myCalculation2);
        }
    }
}
```

Importantly, by convention you will want to use a 'd' suffix after each number.